# Strong name - Sharpshell / LibTiff

Tags: c#, libtiff.net, sharpshell

I'm building a shell extension using Sharpshell and LibTiff/Tiff2Pdf. It's a simple dropdown menu in Windows for converting files. In order for the solution to build all assemblies must require a strong name, include the project itself.

Anyone know how to rebuild LibTiff.Net in Windows with a strong name? If it was my own assembly it would be as easy as adding a new key. However, I'm lost on this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Solved using scenario 2: http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/

Comment: You might try building the library from source code with your key applied.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to re-build the code and then sign it - that's the only way. Maybe the best thing to do would be to directly request that LibTiff.Net provide a signed version of their assembly.

Otherwise, you could disassembly the code (see ildasm at https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&checkda=1&ct=1376595663&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=msdn%24msdn%24msdn&wreply=http%3a%2f%2fmsdn.microsoft.com%2fen-us%2flibrary%2ff7dy01k1.aspx&lc=1033&id=254354&mkt=en-US) but remember that depending on their license, you may be legally forbidden from redistributing it after rebuilding it.